# How to render a PyPDF2.PageObject page to a PIL image in python?

Tags: python-imaging-library, pypdf

Can you help me to render a PDF page opened using PyPDF2 into a PIL image in Python 3?

Comment: See working solution here: https://gist.github.com/jrsmith3/9947838

Comment: pdf2image would be one option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think PyPDF2 can render a pdf page. However, you can use [PyMuPDF](https://github.com/rk700/PyMuPDF) to do this. Here is the [tutorial](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/#rendering-a-page) of PyMuPDF.

Here is an example of rendering with PyMuPDF:

```
import fitz
from PIL import Image

filename = "test.pdf"  # name of pdf file you want to render
n = 0  # n is the page number

#render with PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open(filename)
page = doc.loadPage(n)
pix = page.getPixmap()

#convert to a PIL image
img = Image.frombytes("RGBA", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)
```